# How to make json encode with java from query database resultset?

Tags: json

I want to build an application using jsp, but I have a trouble when I want to get result from query resultset database. I need output json format from query resultset. This is my code if using php-

```
<?php
include "koneksi.php";
$sql = "select * from siswa";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
  while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $json['aaData'][]=$row;
  }
}
echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

result= {"aaData":[["1","212","2312","2312"],["11","ui","ioi","u"],["16","hkljhl","hjkh","jkh"],["17","hkjh","hkjkl","jklj"]]}
the answer is how to make it if I want using jsp with the same result

thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

You would essentially build the JSON string and then convert it to a JSON object.

```
var jsonstring = '{';
//add first element
jsonstring += '"key":"'+valuefromdb+'",';
//add second 
//note that there is no comma on the end of the last element
jsonstring += '"key":"'+valuefromdb+'"';

//end JSON string
jsonstring += '}';

//Convert string to JSON Object
var JSONobj = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
```

A good tool to verify your JSON syntax is JSONLint.
http://jsonlint.com/

I would still recommend doing your database work through PHP since it will help protect your database identity. I would then handle the JSON building in PHP and make your call from javascript using AJAX to get the JSON object from your PHP.

Here is a good video tutorial list that describes everything above in more detail.
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8tl0oOyxE_GMv_QMb1hfkmYCf9IIg8iz